# Json Schema Example for patternProperties

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema

can anyone give me an example of how to use the patternProperties item for json schema?

```
"Example" :
  "type" : "object",
  "patternProperties" :
  {
     <how do I use this>
  }
```

What I want to do in the json file is allow any subitem of "Example" that is starting with A
e.g.:

```
{
  "Example" : 
  {
    "Aaa" : { ...}
  }
}
```

is patternProperties the right choice for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
{
  type: 'object',
  patternProperties: {
    '^A': {
      type: 'string',
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so '^A' must simply be a RegEx? and if the string matches validation goes through?